# GIT rebase overwritten all changes

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-revert

Ok, this time I really messed up with GIT: I worked for a few days offline on a project, and today I tried to commit/push the changes to GitHub. Somehow, there were some conflicts, that I tried to solve with rebase. I ended up with in a branch REBASE 1/2, I used the skip option and mover to REBASE 2/2, I skipped again and...well, guess what? I messed up so much that I ended up overwriting my local project with the latest commit pushed to GitHub, losing 11 days of work!

Now, since I'm sure I staged and committed my changes before the rebase, I thought there was a way to recover this disaster; but when I check with git reflog, this is the top line:

2e73363 HEAD@{0}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master

The problem is, this commit number is from 11 days ago, not from today!

So my questions are:
- where are my commits from today?
- is there any way to revert the rebase I did today, restoring all my changes to the project?

EDIT: this is the full test from reflog:

```
$ git reflog
2e73363 HEAD@{0}: rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master
2e73363 HEAD@{1}: rebase: checkout origin/master
2ff234f HEAD@{2}: commit: added .classpath to commit
8ddcf79 HEAD@{3}: commit: fixed few errrors
e5a6da9 HEAD@{4}: commit: adding hibernate to DAO classes
c6c10bf HEAD@{5}: commit: fixed problems with commit after detached head
0e527a6 HEAD@{6}: commit (merge): added Spring Security
f4ad11a HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from tmp to master
a0a1597 HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from master to tmp
f4ad11a HEAD@{9}: checkout: moving from new-branch to master
f4ad11a HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from master to new-branch
f4ad11a HEAD@{11}: checkout: moving from master to master
f4ad11a HEAD@{12}: checkout: moving from 96e7903b784ae435c042abab33939327b081c138 to master
96e7903 HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from master to 96e7903b784ae435c042abab33939327b081c138
f4ad11a HEAD@{14}: checkout: moving from a0a1597361522b25f4c12463f1bfa2673721eb7b to master
a0a1597 HEAD@{15}: checkout: moving from master to a0a1597
f4ad11a HEAD@{16}: checkout: moving from a0a1597361522b25f4c12463f1bfa2673721eb7b to master
a0a1597 HEAD@{17}: commit: commit from detached head
c40dc30 HEAD@{18}: commit: added Spring Security to admin page
96e7903 HEAD@{19}: checkout: moving from master to 96e7903b784ae435c042abab33939327b081c138
f4ad11a HEAD@{20}: revert: Revert "commicommitt"
96e7903 HEAD@{21}: checkout: moving from 96e7903b784ae435c042abab33939327b081c138 to master
96e7903 HEAD@{22}: checkout: moving from master to 96e7903b784ae435c042abab33939327b081c138
96e7903 HEAD@{23}: commit: commicommitt
f9fc7a1 HEAD@{24}: merge refs/remotes/origin/master: Fast-forward
ff7fc6d HEAD@{25}: commit (initial): Initial commit
```

and this is the output from reflog master:

```
$ git reflog master
2e73363 master@{0}: rebase finished: refs/heads/master onto 2e7336369502768f42174019bf1efbfc9b113d9f
2ff234f master@{1}: commit: added .classpath to commit
8ddcf79 master@{2}: commit: fixed few errrors
e5a6da9 master@{3}: commit: adding hibernate to DAO classes
c6c10bf master@{4}: commit: fixed problems with commit after detached head
0e527a6 master@{5}: commit (merge): added Spring Security
f4ad11a master@{6}: revert: Revert "commicommitt"
96e7903 master@{7}: commit: commicommitt
f9fc7a1 master@{8}: merge refs/remotes/origin/master: Fast-forward
ff7fc6d master@{9}: commit (initial): Initial commit
```

Comment: I don't think the " rebase finished: returning to refs/heads/master" was from the past, i mean, it shows your rebase was successful. What do you have at HEAD@{1} and HEAD@{2}??

Comment: You just found out the hard way 'rebase --skip' means: just get rid of that commit instead of solving the merge conflicts?

Comment: @ Adegbuyi Ademola, this is what I have: 2e73363 HEAD@{1}: rebase: checkout origin/master
2ff234f HEAD@{2}: commit: added .classpath to commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked `ORIG_HEAD`? It's probably still pointing to the branch head before rebase.

Nevertheless `git reflog master`, or replace with your branch, should show all the commits master has been on.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it: using `git reflog master`, I found the commit number before the rebase; then, I reverted to that commit with `git reset --hard`.